# Is patent US6513002 valid? Is there prior art in computer textbooks published prior to 1990?

Tags: prior-art-request, software, data-processing-language, us6513002

About Patent [US6513002](http://www.google.com/patents/US6513002): Rule-based number formatter

It seems to me that many computer textbooks published before 1990 have include exercises about how to write a simple number translation program. I don't think this patent about a number translator is valid, since programs like these have been mentioned in a number of computer programming textbooks.

Does anyone have any specific examples of prior art for US6513002?

Comment: Hi Leo, can you please specify whether you are looking for specific examples of prior art, or are simply asking whether prior art from 1990 might be valid? Thanks!

Comment: Filing date is 1998. Why look for prior before 1990?

Answer (score 3):

To the exact question - it is **not** valid and in force. IBM did not pay the maintance fee due in 2006 and it went abandoned in 2007. I looked it up in Lexis Total Patents. You can use the USPTO maintenance fee shopping window https://ramps.uspto.gov/eram/patentMaintFees.do or [PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hff1NDc1NLYwN3SzcDA08PwyD_YF8zINcYKB-JW97AiCLdBgR0h4Nci992vPIGEHkDHMDRQN_PIz83Vb8gNzTCIDMgHQCGKKj-/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSWdrbUNTUS9JUFJBQUlpQ2dBek15cXpHWUEhIS80QkVqOG8wRmxHaXQtYlhwQUh0Qi83X01PNTE3NTkzMEc5RjAwSUgxUk9TTTYzMDI2L1M3ZlZmODc4MDAyOC9zYS5nZXRCaWI!/). PAIR has a captcha wall.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer, this patent seems to be meaningless.  All it appears to do is take a spoken number and translates it into a numeric representation.  This seems like what many voice-recognition gadgets already do, especially cell-phones.  Plus, besides the initial voice input, the rest is a simple, common algorithm.

Comment: Can you cite a program or device that performs the functions described in the claims, or a publication that describes them, dating from before February 1997? That's what prior art means, and the question is even more specific. Claim 1 does seem to me to be have been obvious then, but some of the other claims are more substantial.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the patent is incorrect. To me it appears to simply concern a method for taking a numerical value ("115") and converting it into a text string ("one hundred fifteen"). Everything based on "rules", which get "identified", of course. Another USPTO joke, if you ask me.